# Making stopwatch/randomizer app but it crashes everytime I try to use one of those two

Tags: android

So, I wanted to make an app that has the main activity in which I can switch between two fragments containing a number randomizer and the other one a stopwatch. The stopwatch, meanwhile, must not stop if I switch to another fragment (it may only stop after I click again a start/stop button). I can switch between them normally, but when I try to generate a random number via button or I try to start the stopwatch, the app crashes. This is what I tried:

Stopwatch fragment:

```
public class frStopwatch extends Fragment {

    View view;
    EditText etTime;
    Button btnStartStop;
    Button btnReset;

    Chronometer chronometer;
    private boolean running;
    private long pauseOffset;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fr_stopwatch, container, false);

        btnStartStop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStartStop);
        btnReset = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
        btnStartStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                chronometer.start();

            }
        });
        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Randomizer fragment:

```
public class frRandomizer extends Fragment {

    View view;
    Button btnRandom;
    EditText etShowNum;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fr_randomizer, container, false);

        btnRandom = view.findViewById(R.id.btnRandom);
        etShowNum = view.findViewById(R.id.etShowNum);
        btnRandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random r = new Random();
                etShowNum.setText(r.nextInt(9));
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

The app crashes on both emulator and mobile phone.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: As @CommonsWare suggested, please check your crash log first. But you may try to change this particular line ```etShowNum.setText(r.nextInt(9))``` to ```etShowNum.setText(String.valueOf(r.nextInt(9)))```.